# How to exclude parent css style in child elements?

Tags: html, css

here I have HTML elements stacked like this,

```css
.center-badge p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-badge">
  <div>
    <p>Get a</p>
    <p><strong>2% rate reduction</strong></p>
    <p>with a</p>
    <p>co-applicant</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I have added the font size as 12px for the center-badge CSS. In this, we need to exclude the strong tag with p. Only the 12px styling has to apply all the p tags but a strong tag.

We have added a global styling for the p as 16px. How to exclude a particular element to not apply the parent CSS.

Is any way to solve this. can we can use the `:not()` for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If an element has `font-size: inherit` or `font-size: someUnitRelativeToTheParent` — and it doesn't matter if that is set explicitly or by the browser stylesheet — then you can't make it not base the font-size on that of the parent element.

Likewise there is no way to write a selector with a condition "Unless the element's children include X" to avoid applying the `font-size` in that particular `p` in the first place.

You can either:

- Explicitly style the `strong` element with a `font-size` that uses absolute units *or*
- Change the DOM in such a way that you can exclude the `p` (e.g. by adding a class to it and adding `:not(.that_class)` to the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

you have applied the global css like this I think.

```
p {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

but once you apply css using the parent class like this way

```
.center-badge p {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

it overrides your global css for `<p>` tag.

now `<strong>` has no browser default font size as `<p>` tag for the `font-size` property.

so you have to define it globally like this way

```
strong {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

or using parent class also you can apply the css like this way.

```
.center-badge strong {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

or you can apply it by giving the `font-size: initial` to the `<strong>` tag like this way.

```
.center-badge strong {
    font-size: initial;
}
```